# unable to properly use checkbox to populate state value in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-state

I have two input fields. when I press the check box the state value stored in `solutestate` should be in the first input box. then if I uncheck the box the value in the second input field should be changed. Both the input box should have an independent state change. I am attaching a codesandbox link which I am trying to edit [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-darkness-c1yfq?file=/src/App.js).

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Jsme } from "jsme-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { default as FormData } from "form-data";

export default function App() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [syncToFirst, setSyncToFirst] = useState();
  const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState();

  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      solute: "",
      solvent: ""
    }
  });

  const formData = new FormData();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={setSoluteState}
      />

      <h1>{solutestate}</h1>
      <input
        className="mr-2 leading-tight"
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setSyncToFirst(event.target.checked ? 1 : 2);
        }}
      />

      <input
        className="mr-2 leading-tight"
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setSyncToFirst(event.target.checked ? 1 : 2);
        }}
      />
      <form>
        <input
          {...register("solute")}
          placeholder="SOLUTE"
          onChange={(e) =>
            syncToFirst === 1
              ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
              : setInput1(e.target.value)
          }
          value={syncToFirst === 1 ? solutestate : input1}
        />
        <input
          {...register("solvent")}
          placeholder="SOLVENT"
          onChange={(e) =>
            syncToFirst === 2
              ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
              : input2(e.target.value)
          }
          value={syncToFirst === 2 ? solutestate : input2}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? What should happen when you uncheck the first checkbox? What should happen when you check and uncheck the other checkbox?

Comment: @hellogoodnight When I check the first box the state value should be in the first input field. When I uncheck the first box and check the second box the state value should be in the second input field. While checking the second box and unchecking the first box the value in the first input field should retain. I am doing a prediction using both the input fields btw.

Comment: What should happen if both checkboxes are checked?

Comment: @hellogoodnight we can do the same thing with one check box also. if checked it should populate in the first input field and when unchecked it should populate the second input field

Comment: @hellogoodnight same value should given to both input field at a time when both are checked

Comment: So basically, if a checkbox is checked, then it's corresponding text field should print?

Comment: Yes @hellogoodnight

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow you but for starters you should put the checkbox values in state variables. I don't really understand if you care about the sequence of the checks, I.E. which checkbox was checked last.

```
export default function App() {
  // I added the following state variables to keep track of checkboxes
  const [isCheckbox1Checked, setIsCheckbox1Checked] = useState(false);
  const [isCheckbox2Checked, setIsCheckbox2Checked] = useState(false);
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [syncToFirst, setSyncToFirst] = useState();
  const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState();

  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      solute: "",
      solvent: ""
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={setSoluteState}
      />

      <h1>{solutestate}</h1>
      <input
        className="mr-2 leading-tight"
        type="checkbox"
        value={isCheckbox1Checked}
        onChange={() => setIsCheckbox1Checked(prev => !prev)}
      />

      <input
        className="mr-2 leading-tight"
        type="checkbox"
        value={isCheckbox2Checked}
        onChange={() => setIsCheckbox2Checked(prev => !prev)}
      />
      <form>
        <input
          {...register("solute")}
          placeholder="SOLUTE"
          onChange={(e) =>
            syncToFirst === 1
              ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
              : setInput1(e.target.value)
          }
          value={isCheckbox1Checked ? solutestate : input1}
        />
        <input
          {...register("solvent")}
          placeholder="SOLVENT"
          onChange={(e) =>
            syncToFirst === 2
              ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
              : input2(e.target.value)
          }
          value={isCheckbox2Checked ? solutestate : input2}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code still is wierd, could you please explain what behaviour you want from the text input fields?

Comment: I was actually doing prediction of the two text input fields. The statevalue to the input fields is getting from an editor as shown in the figure. https://codesandbox.io/s/little-darkness-c1yfq?file=/src/App.js using this link you can see what I was talking about

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what behaviour you want your code to have. Good luck

Comment: whenever I uncheck the box the value is disappearing. Once entered it should be there if I uncheck also. If not I cannot write two different values in the input text field

Comment: and whenever i try to type normal in the second input text field it is throwing error as `input2 is not a function`